# How can i shuffle questions in this code as i am getting error with Collections.shuffle(mPower1QuestionBank, new Random(mQuestionNumber)) code

Tags: java, android

How can i shuffle questions in this code as i am getting error with `Collections.shuffle(mPower1QuestionBank, new Random(mQuestionNumber))`

```
private void updateQuestion() {
    if (mQuestionNumber < 30 ) {
        // if questions are not over then do this
        mQuestionView.setText(mPower1QuestionBank.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mQuestionImageView.setImageResource(mPower1QuestionBank.getQuestionImages(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mPower1QuestionBank.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mPower1QuestionBank.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mPower1QuestionBank.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice4.setText(mPower1QuestionBank.getChoice4(mQuestionNumber));

        mAnswer = mPower1QuestionBank.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
           radioGroup.clearCheck();
           mQuestionNumber++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `i am getting error` and what is it?

Comment: please provide what is the error

Comment: after adding this code app closes automatically, or app is not running